# Does H.264 encoded video with BT.709 matrix include any gamma adjustment?

Tags: ios, video, ffmpeg, metal

I have read the [BT.709 spec](https://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-r/rec/bt/R-REC-BT.709-6-201506-I!!PDF-E.pdf) a number of times and the thing that is just not clear is should an encoded H.264 bitstream actually apply any gamma curve to the encoded data? Note the specific mention of a gamma like formula in the BT.709 spec. Apple provided examples of OpenGL or Metal shaders that read YUV data from CoreVideo provided buffers do not do any sort of gamma adjustment. YUV values are being read and processed as though they are simple linear values. I also examined the source code of ffmpeg and found no gamma adjustments being applied after the BT.709 scaling step. I then [created a test video](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53806290/763355) with just two linear grayscale colors 5 and 26 corresponding to 2% and 10% levels. When converted to H.264 with both ffmpeg and iMovie, the output BT.709 values are (YCbCr) (20 128 128) and (38 128 128) and these values exactly match the output of the BT.709 conversion matrix without any gamma adjustment.

A great piece of background on this topic can be found at [Quicktime Gamma Bug](https://vitrolite.wordpress.com/2010/12/31/quicktime_gamma_bug/). It seems that some historical issues with Quicktime and Adobe encoders were improperly doing different gamma adjustments and the results made video streams look awful on different players. This is really confusing because if you compare to [sRGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB), it clearly indicates how to apply a gamma encoding and then decode it to convert between sRGB and linear. Why does BT.709 go into so much detail about the same sort of gamma adjustment curve if no gamma adjustment is applied after the matrix step when creating a h.264 data stream? Are all the color steps in a h.264 stream meant to be coded as straight linear (gamma 1.0) values?

In case specific example input would make things more clear, I am attaching 3 color bar images, the exact values of different colors can be displayed in an image editor with these image files.

This first image is in the sRGB colorspace and is tagged as sRGB.

[image: sRGB colorspace]

This second image has been converted to the linear RGB colorspace and is tagged with a linear RGB profile.

[image: linear RGB colorspace]

This third image has been converted to REC.709 profile levels with Rec709-elle-V4-rec709.icc from [elles_icc_profiles](https://github.com/ellelstone/elles_icc_profiles)
. This seems to be what one would need to do to simulate "camera" gamma as described in BT.709.

[image: BT.709 colorspace ICC]

Note how the sRGB value in the lower right corner (0x555555) becomes linear RGB (0x171717) and the BT.709 gamma encoded value becomes (0x464646). What is unclear is if I should be passing a linear RGB value into ffmpeg or if I should be passing an already BT.709 gamma encoded value which would then need to be decoded in the client before the linear conversion Matrix step to get back to RGB.

Update:

Based on the feedback, I have updated my C based implementation and Metal shader and uploaded to github as an iOS example project [MetalBT709Decoder](https://github.com/mdejong/MetalBT709Decoder).

Encoding a normalized linear RGB value is implemented like this:

```
static inline
int BT709_convertLinearRGBToYCbCr(
                            float Rn,
                            float Gn,
                            float Bn,
                            int *YPtr,
                            int *CbPtr,
                            int *CrPtr,
                            int applyGammaMap)
{
  // Gamma adjustment to non-linear value

  if (applyGammaMap) {
    Rn = BT709_linearNormToNonLinear(Rn);
    Gn = BT709_linearNormToNonLinear(Gn);
    Bn = BT709_linearNormToNonLinear(Bn);
  }

  // https://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-r/rec/bt/R-REC-BT.709-6-201506-I!!PDF-E.pdf

  float Ey = (Kr * Rn) + (Kg * Gn) + (Kb * Bn);
  float Eb = (Bn - Ey) / Eb_minus_Ey_Range;
  float Er = (Rn - Ey) / Er_minus_Ey_Range;

  // Quant Y to range [16, 235] (inclusive 219 values)
  // Quant Eb, Er to range [16, 240] (inclusive 224 values, centered at 128)

  float AdjEy = (Ey * (YMax-YMin)) + 16;
  float AdjEb = (Eb * (UVMax-UVMin)) + 128;
  float AdjEr = (Er * (UVMax-UVMin)) + 128;

  *YPtr = (int) round(AdjEy);
  *CbPtr = (int) round(AdjEb);
  *CrPtr = (int) round(AdjEr);

  return 0;
}
```

Decoding from YCbCr to linear RGB is implemented like so:

```
static inline
int BT709_convertYCbCrToLinearRGB(
                             int Y,
                             int Cb,
                             int Cr,
                             float *RPtr,
                             float *GPtr,
                             float *BPtr,
                             int applyGammaMap)
{
  // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr#ITU-R_BT.709_conversion
  // http://www.niwa.nu/2013/05/understanding-yuv-values/

  // Normalize Y to range [0 255]
  //
  // Note that the matrix multiply will adjust
  // this byte normalized range to account for
  // the limited range [16 235]

  float Yn = (Y - 16) * (1.0f / 255.0f);

  // Normalize Cb and CR with zero at 128 and range [0 255]
  // Note that matrix will adjust to limited range [16 240]

  float Cbn = (Cb - 128) * (1.0f / 255.0f);
  float Crn = (Cr - 128) * (1.0f / 255.0f);

  const float YScale = 255.0f / (YMax-YMin);
  const float UVScale = 255.0f / (UVMax-UVMin);

  const
  float BT709Mat[] = {
    YScale,   0.000f,  (UVScale * Er_minus_Ey_Range),
    YScale, (-1.0f * UVScale * Eb_minus_Ey_Range * Kb_over_Kg),  (-1.0f * UVScale * Er_minus_Ey_Range * Kr_over_Kg),
    YScale, (UVScale * Eb_minus_Ey_Range),  0.000f,
  };

  // Matrix multiply operation
  //
  // rgb = BT709Mat * YCbCr

  // Convert input Y, Cb, Cr to normalized float values

  float Rn = (Yn * BT709Mat[0]) + (Cbn * BT709Mat[1]) + (Crn * BT709Mat[2]);
  float Gn = (Yn * BT709Mat[3]) + (Cbn * BT709Mat[4]) + (Crn * BT709Mat[5]);
  float Bn = (Yn * BT709Mat[6]) + (Cbn * BT709Mat[7]) + (Crn * BT709Mat[8]);

  // Saturate normalzied linear (R G B) to range [0.0, 1.0]

  Rn = saturatef(Rn);
  Gn = saturatef(Gn);
  Bn = saturatef(Bn);

  // Gamma adjustment for RGB components after matrix transform

  if (applyGammaMap) {
    Rn = BT709_nonLinearNormToLinear(Rn);
    Gn = BT709_nonLinearNormToLinear(Gn);
    Bn = BT709_nonLinearNormToLinear(Bn);
  }

  *RPtr = Rn;
  *GPtr = Gn;
  *BPtr = Bn;

  return 0;
}
```

I believe this logic is implemented correctly, but I am having a very difficult time validating the results. When I generate a .m4v file that contains gamma adjusted color values (osxcolor_test_image_24bit_BT709.m4v), the result come out as expected. But a test case like (bars_709_Frame01.m4v) that I found [here](https://lists.libav.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2010-December/028210.html) does not seem to work as the color bar values seem to be encoded as linear (no gamma adjustment).

For a SMPTE test pattern, the 0.75 graylevel is linear RGB (191 191 191), should this RGB be encoded with no gamma adjustment as (Y Cb Cr) (180 128 128) or should the value in the bitstream appear as the gamma adjusted (Y Cb Cr) (206 128 128)?

(follow up)
After doing additional research into this gamma issue, it has become clear that what Apple is actually doing in AVFoundation is using a 1.961 gamma function. This is the case when encoding with AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor, when using vImage, or with CoreVideo APIs. This piecewise gamma function is defined as follows:

```
#define APPLE_GAMMA_196 (1.960938f)

static inline
float Apple196_nonLinearNormToLinear(float normV) {
  const float xIntercept = 0.05583828f;

  if (normV < xIntercept) {
    normV *= (1.0f / 16.0f);
  } else {
    const float gamma = APPLE_GAMMA_196;
    normV = pow(normV, gamma);
  }

  return normV;
}

static inline
float Apple196_linearNormToNonLinear(float normV) {
  const float yIntercept = 0.00349f;

  if (normV < yIntercept) {
    normV *= 16.0f;
  } else {
    const float gamma = 1.0f / APPLE_GAMMA_196;
    normV = pow(normV, gamma);
  }

  return normV;
}
```

Comment: The H264 bitstream doesn't "apply any gamma curve". The encoder will store the color properties, if present, as VUI flags, and encode the YUV data as presented. At the playback end, the H264 decoder will read those flags if present and pass them on, so the scalers, which convert the raster data to RGB, can take heed and adjust accordingly. The preceding is with reference to ffmpeg.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What does "adjust accordingly" mean? Would a decoder be required to apply a non-linear to linear gamma adjustment before converting YCbCr data back to RGB data, assuming the correct transfer properties flag is included in the bitstream?

Comment: There are RGB sensors on a camera. Basically, those values get converted to YUV. The conversion is nonlinear and the weighting function is the transfer characteristic or gamma. The encoder gets input YUV and compresses that. It stores the transfer function as metadata, if provided. The deocder generates YUV, ideally close to the input values - the gamma doesn't play a role. But the metadata is attached. The scaler, not the decoder, which converts YUV to RGB, takes heed and adjusts/selects its conversion function accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original question: Does H.264 encoded video with BT.709 matrix include any gamma adjustment?

The encoded video only contains gamma adjustment - if you feed the encoder gamma adjusted values.

A H.264 encoder doesn't care about the transfer characteristics.
So if you compress linear and then decompress - you'll get linear.
So if you compress with gamma and then decompress - you'll get gamma.

Or if your bits are encoded with a Rec. 709 transfer function - the encoder won't change the gamma.

But you can specify the transfer characteristic in the H.264 stream as metadata. (Rec. ITU-T H.264 (04/2017) E.1.1  VUI parameters syntax). So the encoded streams carries the color space information around but it is not used in encoding or decoding.

I would assume that 8 bit video always contains a non linear transfer function. Otherwise you would use the 8 bit fairly unwisely.

If you convert to linear to do effects and composition - I'd recommend increasing the bit depth or linearizing into floats.

A color space consists of primaries, transfer function and matrix coefficients.
The gamma adjustment is encoded in the transfer function (and not in the matrix).

Comment: Ahh, I see. I believe my confusion was because I found an Apple provided Quicktime test pattern that had 75% gray indicated as Y = 180, but after more thought it seems that the test bars are encoded with as linear (no gamma adjust). I manually generated H.264 using AVFoundation with linear R G B (192 192 192) and that gets encoded as gamma adjusted Rec.709 Y Cb Cr (211 128 128).

Comment: After more testing, it appears that this Quicktime test video is in fact encoded with the gamma adjustment defined in BT.709. A properly implemented decoder needs to remove this gamma encoding from the decoded R',G',B' signals after the matrix transform for the output to be properly converted to linear.

Comment: I don’t think a decoder should change the color space. I’d have a dedicated color space converter.  But it would be better performing if decoding into the desired color space can be done in a single path over the data.

Comment: Well, thing is in the case of BT.709 -> sRGB the colorspace conversion is simple because 709 and sRGB share the same RGB primaries. So, you only need to convert the gamma encoding to get the right output. What I have implemented is logic that always assumes the input in the encoded .m4v file is in BT.709 and then that gamma is converted to linear inside a Metal shader on the GPU. The output of the shader can then be automatically converted to sRGB gamma by the hardware. Then this sRGB color representation is sent to the display. The Metal source code AAPLShaders.metal contains all the details.

Comment: Ahh - this sounds pretty efficient.