# Unexpected output converting CVPixelBuffer to MTLTexture

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, metal

I am extracting SampleBuffers from the AVAsset using AVAssetReader. I am converting each CMSampleBuffer to MTLTexture every iteration using the code snippet below. however, I am getting expected CVPixelBuffer but when I try to convert it I got [image: unexpected output]. expected output is [image: this]..

I already try debugging width and height which is accurate, I try to use the different video same issue occurred, tried creating different textureCache. same issue.

```swift
    func convertToMTLTexture(sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?) -> MTLTexture? {


        if let textureCache = textureCache,
            let sampleBuffer = sampleBuffer,
            let imageBuffer:CVPixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) {

            let width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer)
            let height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer)

            var texture: CVMetalTexture?
            CVMetalTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault, textureCache,
                                                      imageBuffer, nil, .bgra8Unorm, width, height, 0, &texture)

            if let texture = texture {
                return CVMetalTextureGetTexture(texture)
            }

        }
        return nil
    }
```

Comment: What is the pixel format of your CMSampleBuffers? (My guess: YCbCr)

Comment: You can find working example code for this type of problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53911662/does-h-264-encoded-video-with-bt-709-matrix-include-any-gamma-adjustment