# RGB to Gray Scale yet pixel values seem wrong

Tags: swift, rgb, pixel, tensorflow2.0, grayscale

I have a model that I built using tensorflow 2.0 / Keras. The input is an image that has 28x28 with 1 channel. The model is saved and converted into .tflite and utilized in my swift ios application. Unfortunately, when invoke the interpreter I get drastically different predictions than expected. When I investigate further, it seems that my image preparation may be wrong. Here are the steps I take before feeding the pixel array into my model.

1. load image.
2. convert a image to grayscale
3. normalize the pixel values by dividing by 255.

[image]  <-this may be hard to see but there is an image to the left of this text with one black pixel in the top left and bottom right. In a pixel array, I would expect the first and last pixel to be 0(black) and the rest be 255(white). However, when I inspect the CVPixelBuffer, I notice that the pixel values are very different. See below. Why are the pixel values seemingly different than the displayed image.

```
1
252
255
253
255
255
255
253
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
253
255
253
254
253
255
254
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
255
248
255
253
255
255
248
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
255
255
255
255
253
255
255
252
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
255
250
254
255
248
253
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
255
255
255
251
255
255
254
253
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
250
255
255
255
255
248
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
255
255
255
255
253
255
251
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
255
```

Here is my code

```
let im =  UIImage(named: "dotsgray")!
let i = (im.pixelBufferGray(width: 28, height: 28))!
i.normalize()



extension UIImage {
  public func pixelBufferGray(width: Int, height: Int) -> CVPixelBuffer? {
        return pixelBuffer(width: width, height: height,
                           pixelFormatType: kCVPixelFormatType_OneComponent8,
                           colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray(),
                           alphaInfo: .none)
    }


    func pixelBuffer(width: Int, height: Int, pixelFormatType: OSType,
                     colorSpace: CGColorSpace, alphaInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo) -> CVPixelBuffer? {
        var maybePixelBuffer: CVPixelBuffer?
        let attrs = [kCVPixelBufferCGImageCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue,
                     kCVPixelBufferCGBitmapContextCompatibilityKey: kCFBooleanTrue]
        let status = CVPixelBufferCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                         width,
                                         height,
                                         pixelFormatType,
                                         attrs as CFDictionary,
                                         &maybePixelBuffer)

        guard status == kCVReturnSuccess, let pixelBuffer = maybePixelBuffer else {
            return nil
        }

        CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        let pixelData = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(pixelBuffer)

        guard let context = CGContext(data: pixelData,
                                      width: width,
                                      height: height,
                                      bitsPerComponent: 8,
                                      bytesPerRow: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer),
                                      space: colorSpace,
                                      bitmapInfo: alphaInfo.rawValue)
            else {
                return nil
        }

        UIGraphicsPushContext(context)
        context.translateBy(x: 0, y: CGFloat(height))
        context.scaleBy(x: 1, y: -1)
        self.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
        UIGraphicsPopContext()

        CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(pixelBuffer, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
        return pixelBuffer
    }
}

extension CVPixelBuffer {

func normalize() {
  // 1
  let bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(self)
  let totalBytes = CVPixelBufferGetDataSize(self)

  let width = bytesPerRow / MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size
  let height = totalBytes / bytesPerRow

  // 2
  CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(self, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))

  // 3
  let floatBuffer = unsafeBitCast(
    CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(self),
    to: UnsafeMutablePointer<Double>.self)

  // 4
  var minPixel: Double = 1.0
  var maxPixel: Double = 0.0

  // 5
  for i in 0 ..< width * height {
    let pixel = floatBuffer[i]
    minPixel = min(pixel, minPixel)
    maxPixel = max(pixel, maxPixel)
  }

  // 6
  let range = maxPixel - minPixel

  // 7
  for i in 0 ..< width * height {
    let pixel = floatBuffer[i]
    floatBuffer[i] = (pixel - minPixel) / range
  }

  // 8
  CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(self, CVPixelBufferLockFlags(rawValue: 0))
}
```

Comment: check the value of `CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pixelBuffer)`

Comment: CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(self) is 64 and CVPixelBufferGetDataSize(self) is 1792

Comment: You should write code to do the RGB -> Grayscale conversion and test that logic without involving pixel buffers and CoreVideo APIs. You need to handle both colorspace conversion and gamma. Then once your code is fully testing and known to be working, apply that logic row by row to the CoreVideo supplied pixels. For detailed info on RGB -> Grayscale see this question (source code also provided) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53911662/does-h-264-encoded-video-with-bt-709-matrix-include-any-gamma-adjustment

Answer (score 1):

Your `normalize()` is completely wrong for your purpose.

It normalize the `Double`-based pixel buffer into 0.0...1.0, but you are not creating a pixel buffer of `Double`.

Your `pixelBufferGray(width:height:)` creates a pixel buffer of `UInt8`, as you provide `kCVPixelFormatType_OneComponent8` for `pixelFormatType`.

Remove `i.normalize()` and inspect the pixel buffer`. You will see what you expect.

---

You may need to *pack* the pixel buffer, as it use only 28 bytes of each 64-byte row, but that's another issue.